# Add html to a map marker angular Google maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I need a way to customize the map marker in Angular with Google maps. I searched many places, but found only icons which can be added.

So please help me out to add HTML to my marker(HTML to be shown as a marker).

```js
function getMap(form,scope) {
 scope.map = {
   center: {
     latitude: 40.1451,
     longitude: -99.6680
   },
   zoom: 4
 };
 scope.options = {
   scrollwheel: true
 };
 function createRandomMarker(i, data, idKey) {
   // var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   if (idKey == null) {
     idKey = "id";
   }
   var ret = {
     latitude: data.latitude,
     longitude: data.longitude,
     title: 'm' + i,
     icon: {
           url: 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png',
           scaledSize: { width: 36, height: 48 }
     }

   };
   ret[idKey] = i;
   return ret;
 }

 scope.randomMarkers = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < (form.length); i++) {
    console.log(form[i].latitude+","+form[i].list_id)
   if ((form[i].latitude != null) && (form[i].longitude != null))
     {
       scope.randomMarkers.push(createRandomMarker(i, form[i]))
     }
 }
 return scope.randomMarkers
}
```

I need HTML, in place of that icon on the marker creation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check [googlemaps/js-rich-marker](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker)